# Is there any algorithm for creating 3D lightning?

Tags: 3d, coordinates

Is there any algorithm for generating lightning?
Lets say, you input the starting and ending coordinates (x,y,z) and out comes an array of coordinates to show where the lightning goes.
It doesn't have to be scientifically accurate but as long it looks random and unpredictable

EDIT: I found [this](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/FAST_LIGHTNING/index.html), but can't figure out how to put this in to C/++ code. There is a 2D example provided but I want 3D :O

EDIT2: The output might be something like this:

```
struct coord3 { int x, y, z; };

struct line
{
    unsigned char lumo;
    coord3 start;
    coord3 end;
};

line* lightning = new line[n]; // each element of the array would be a line that
                               // needs to be drawn for the lightning so the
                               // lightning can "fork" and can have different
                               // brightnesses
```

Comment: The sample you found will bleed you dry in 3d. It actually tries to solve the electrical equations.

Comment: Eww. But I still want to use it :O

Answer (score 2):

If you need a set begin and endpoint then you'll have to generate the points inbetween. Start by randomly cutting the line (begin - end) in a number of segments. For each point generate a random amplitude within a given range and scale it (or scale your random range) so the points closer to the beginning and end can't displace as much. Next for each segment endpoint do a random to see if a fork should be created there, give it a random number of segments and repeat the same process for the fork. Forks can have a fixed endpoint as well if you want. Nodes should have a random value to decide how long they should be kept the same. This way you'll get lightning going from a to b with some points staying in place a few frames longer, some a few frames shorter and some random forking.

Comment: Could you link to an example of this in action?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fiZtLkOIQ4&feature=related

Comment: Hmm. Looks okay... but it doesn't really look "lightningty"

Comment: I guess you'd have to add more (and thinner) forks, more random segment lengths, play with the delay, select your (forked) endpoints wisely. Sorry, it was the closest I could think of, and it was a couple of years ago - I bet it could be improved, but at least it's a starting point?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAPTrlTq0q4&feature=related around the 8 second mark...looks lightningey to me? Alternatively, there are some vids on the net of highly slomo lightning, analyze and try to break it down.

Comment: Hmm, it only looks good if it is in flashes...

Comment: @Kotaru: if you slowed down the rate at which the lightning bolt changes, then it might look better. Looks pretty good to me though...

Comment: Yeah, looks pretty lightning-like to me. The longer it is displayed, the more time you'll have to pick holes in it: for flashes it should look fine.

Comment: I guess for lightning would look more like lightning if you start with the center 'beam'overbright and have it stay fairly in place (just have some nodes move a bit) and have it fade out instead of jump around to simulate retention of vision. The forks should probably move a bit more erratic. Like I said, examine slomo footage - this was made by just trying, I suggest you do the same - experiment, it's a big part of gamedev, and it wouldn't be fun if it was all solved for us, we might as well go code databases.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)? You could also have a small random chance of branching at each step.

Ah, you wanted ending coordinates too. Then just weight your directional probability based on how many steps you are from the ending point. The fewer steps remaining, the more chance of going toward the desired endpoint.

Comment: Too random. I don't think it would look as much like lightning. I could try it though

Comment: This is basically what I've done before in 2D; it worked out fairly well. The trick is to severely limit the deflection angle at each 'step' - lightning never really goes "sideways" so you're looking for something like 5 to 10 degrees off the current direction. I also forked out some very small branches of the lightning occasionally but that got kind of expensive.

After about halfway you can start bringing it back around; it actually doesn't look bad if you just traverse the angles in reverse order so you end up with a symmetrical lightning fork.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally try with [L-System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system). I wouldn't be surprised if there are examples you could find with google.